# How to Validate Multiple Email Addresses in a long text field using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I want the regular expression to validate multiple email address for a long text field separated by comma but validation should be put so that field should accept the data in the email ID format (ex: `xyz@aig.com`,`@xyz@abc.in`,`xyz@abc.uk`)only.

I have tried the regular expression:-

```
^([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9.-]+@(([aig.com])|([abc.in])|([abc.uk]))+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}(\s*(;|,)\s*|\s*$))+$)
```

This expression is also accepting the email id if user enters (ex: abc@aig.uk,abc@aig.in)

Comment: Regular expressions [don't make good parsers for email addresses](/q/201323/4850040).  Are you really unable to use a more appropriate parser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to validate comma separated email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870223/regular-expression-to-validate-comma-separated-email-addresses)

Comment: What does "This expression is also accepting the email id if user enters (ex: abc@aig.uk,abc@aig.in)" mean? I'm not entirely sure how that's different from what you were asking for before. You may want to specify what kind of input you'll have, and what kind of output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to validate specified list:

```
^(?:(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.-]*@(?:aig\.com|abc\.in|abc\.uk))(?:,(?!$)|$))*$
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/5F5NwI/1). And if negative lookaheads are not acceptable, than this:

```
^(?:(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.-]*@(?:aig\.com|abc\.in|abc\.uk)),)*(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.-]*@(?:aig\.com|abc\.in|abc\.uk))$
```

Worth noting: `(?:aig\.com|abc\.in|abc\.uk)` matches any of `aig.com`, `abc.in`, `abc.uk`.

In your attempt `[]` where not needed as `[aig.com]` matches `a`, `acc.cc.s` or any permutation of symbols inside square brackets.

Also `(?:,(?!$)|$)` matches either `,` (if it's not last symbol of the line) or end of the string.

Comment: Hi, This regex is working for me but one error is occurred. If i enter value (ex:- abc@aig.com, OR abc@aig.com,xyz@abc.uk,). This is accepting comma if no values passed after the comma. But the vaildation should be failed  if no value is entered after comma. Can you please help me to solve this query

Comment: @Bhumika, corrected initial suggestion (by adding negative lookahead), and also added regex for case if lookaheads are not desirable.